# Is there a way to configure the maven-compiler-plugin to work with relative paths for the source files?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, portability, maven-compiler-plugin

The `maven-compiler-plugin` when it compiles `src` or `test` classes it generates in the `target` output directory a list with all the Java files it compiled (`inputFiles.lst`). E.g. `target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst`

The Java files listed in this file contains the absolute paths of the compiled Java files (one per line):

```
/tmp/build/8565a572/my-maven-project/my-module/src/main/java/com/example/MyClass.java
```

On the contrary, the generated files are also listed in the same directory in the file `createdFiles.lst` but with the relative paths:

```
com/example/MyClass.class
```

This make this `target` directory not portable (without extra workarounds) and this build cannot be reused. (sent by email or between CI/CD job containers that use the random path visible in the `inputFiles.lst` file.

Can the `maven-compiler-plugin` plugin be configured to use relative paths of the Java sources? I would like `inputFiles.lst` to save only the relative paths:

```
src/main/java/com/example/MyClass.java
```

**Use case**: in a Concourse (CI/CD) environment, where the built classes could be reused to accelerate the CI/CD jobs - build once, reuse in all subsequent steps. The CI/CD pipelines contains more than 10 things to do with the code (ignore the order and the meaning, just consider that there are many such things one can do):

- compilation (compile just here, reuse later)
- dependency checks
- unit testing
- coverage reporting
- compliance and security checks
- integration tests
- end-to-end/system tests
- package
- etc.

Because of the absolute paths (**note**: `8565a572` vs `19ad4352`), even if I move the `target` directory along with CI/CD jobs, the code is always compiled from scratch:

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1840 source files to /tmp/build/19ad4352/my-maven-project/my-module/target/classes
```

And if you repeat this operation multiple times in the CI/CD you end up in minutes lost/waited for each commit.

And as an example, `mvn test-compile` for single module (500 Java files) takes **20 seconds** when the compilation is performed vs. **5 seconds** when the built classes are being reused/cached/passed-over.

A workaround would be to `sed`-and-replace in all `inputFiles.lst` to update the new current absolute paths.

Comment: First why is the target directory not portable cause it works on Linux, Windows, Mac etc. The target directory is not intended to be cached and transfered around ...What do you mean by reuse in all subsequent tests? And why would you like to reused the target/classes or target/test-clases?  can you describe more in details what the real problem is?

Comment: I updated the "Use case"  section of the question.

Comment: Regarding the real problem: trying to avoid one single monster job that contains `mvn release` and split it into smaller jobs. Also the projects is a multi-module (single repo) project and this will help parallelising the individual modules. This makes the pipeline fail faster and be more descriptive (visually and failure notification) at which steps in the release process the problems are (which step, which module).

Comment: Based on your description you are trying to decompose the life cycle cause all of the steps you are describing are part of the maven lifecycle . You can of course run your build in paralllization `mvn -T 3 ...` and using a multi module build you already reuse the compiled part within the tests. cause Unit testing is done within the same module. Integration is something different ...and e2e tests as well. package can not being done after e2e cause already for integration tests you need the packages (jar's)... otherwise you are testing not the real app in e2e nor in IT's...

Comment: If you like to parallelize on module base you need to rewrite Maven Core cause the dependency resolution to get the order of the modules is part of it. I've already done such a thing for a large C++ build 10 years ago. This sounds exactly like the same. But you need to have all artifacts/deps somewhere available over the whole nodes which are building parts of it will be the hardest problem you have to solve which will end up in common cache/virtual mount for all build task/jobs to access the different parts of the build. How long does your build take?

Comment: How many modules do you have? How many Tests/IT's/E2E Tests do you have and how long does it take? Have you parallelized your unit tests? Integration tests and E2E tests? I've done that to drop down time for E2E tests from 4 hours down to 15 minutes...which needs to have a very good hardware...etc. Furthermore if a build in Maven fails it shows very quickly where the problem is related? What would the advantage of such a separated pipeline...

Comment: BTW: Can you explain what `Dependency Check` is? Don't get me wrong but are you familiar with Maven life cycle? Cause the points you have listed do not look like it?

Comment: I want to make sure that if version `1.2.3` of `my-licensed.jar` is used, a message is sent to the purchase department that they have to pay a new license. I also want to send to the security department when version `6.6.6` of `my-vulnerable.jar` is used because this has been recently published in the internal security bulletin with a critical with high risk. Think of `dependency:tree` and do all sorts of crazy stuff on it.

Comment: Regarding the modules, there are dozens of modules. Hundreds to thousands of unit tests per module. There is one single pipeline but the jobs in it are paralleled. The advantage is to: A. still use one single pipeline with a fan-in at the end when all modules are tested. B. Have all erroneous modules be reported in parallel to the responsible team instead of "serialising" problem solving (i.e. maven only would fail and stop). So we use all sorts of `-Dmaven....skip=true`, `-P', `-pl`, `-am` to trim down all these jobs to the corresponding modules.

Comment: Regarding the "Based on your description ..." comment above, remember the following fragment of the question: "ignore the order and the meaning". I.e. I invented the list. The question is: how can I avoid recompiling the code every time? Or, how can force `maven-compiler-plugin` to NOT re-compile, but reuse the given classes I give to it?

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay It sounds a bit like you are trying to write your own build tool...

Comment: Based on your comment about `my-licensed.jar` you can not use a version of jar which is licensed before you have payed the license fee. I don't want to send a mail I want to get an information about it (can being by sonatype security scanner and many other tools as well) which will produce a warning in your build which should alert a developer. can also being done via sending information via CI and also prevents getting that branch onto master etc. The dependency:tree as you mentioned is in your pom and is managed by developers so I don't the problem? Or misunderstand the problem?

Comment: Regarding you modules. You can run maven and fail at the end (--fail-at-end) and get a comprehensive report about the failed unit tests. This is usually called an unstable build where afterwards the culprits of that build (usually a branch) will get an email or other kind of informations (slack, mattermoster etc.)  If you have a large number of tests its a good idea to run unit tests in parallel and also let the build run in parallel via `-T 3..` ...I have run builds with 800+ modules in less than 15 minutes (8000+ unit tests) etc. plus security scan etc.

Comment: Can you give some number about the number of modules / tests / build time / etc. you have? How many lines of code (counted by SonarQube for example) ...to get an impression about the size?

Comment: Based on your example of compiling code. You wrote 500 classes taking 20 seconds to compile? This is a single module which is compiled exactly once during a build if you have a multi module build. The test classes will not reused (by default) cause they are unit tests which are locally to the module. The production classes will be packaged into a jar file and being resued by other modules as dependency. So if you build a particular state of your code (git hash) this is needed to do only once?

Comment: I just considering your mentioned number of 500 classes taking 20 seconds. I'm currently building a complete project with 40 modules 1800 classes 44 seconds (incl. xsd generation etc.) via `mvn test-compile` on my own laptop..picked up a single module of that build with 328 class takes 2 second to compile...the whole project has about ca. 40.000 lines of code (SonarQube). The CI system (Jenkins) is a bit faster..

Comment: We are running the build (ca. 3-4 minutes inkl. unit tests ca. 3.500 ink. upload to our repository manager); CVE Analysis take around 2 minute in parallel with the SonarQube analysis. The maven build is running with a single thread not parallelized yet. Currently running unit tests (ca. 3500) takes about 1.5 minutes...On my laptop running whole project `mvn test` take 2:45 minutes using `mvn -T 3 test` take 2:00 minutes ... ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wanna reuse the Maven cache, actually the same thing happened to me recently, I found one of my projects always recompile the module, but the others don't. The version of `maven-compiler-plugin` is 3.6.0.

As a matter of fact, there is a known bug in `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.1. Related issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209. If you're not using that version, you can check is there an empty java file in the project that never compiles into a class file. Or maybe there're only comments in it.

e.g.

```
/*
 * I will write some code in the future
 */
package foo;
```

**You can use the debug mode by running Maven with `-X` and have a look at the output message, it's really helpful to debug Maven and find the the reason.**

[image]

For me, this empty file is the reason that Maven always recompiles the module, so deleting that file works for me.

[image]